# How to ignore d3.js zoom behavior if scale is maxed/minimal?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

Given an SVG with `d3.behavior.zoom` with a determined `scaleExtent`, that gets zoomed with the mouse wheel event:

- If the scale is the minimum (that is, the SVG is completely zoomed-out), or
- If the scale is maximal (that is, the SVG is completely zoomed-in)

How to make the zoom event be ignored and get the mouse wheel event to proceed normally (therefore making the page scroll up/down?)

Comment: couldn't you just make a variable = false, when the zoom is max/min change var to true, if var=true, zoom scale = 1,1 (i.e disable it) then if that var=true start the scrolling ability ?

Comment: But how to start the scrolling ability then...?

Comment: overflow: scroll ? .... in your css for the SVG ?

Comment: so if(var=true){ d3.select('svg').classed('scroll', true)} else{ d3.select('svg').classed('scroll', false)) ..... and also change zoom depending if the var =true/false

Answer (score -1):

Not to clear in the comments but maybe something like or similar may work:

JS:

pseudo for zoom :

```
var zoomEnd = false;
if(zoom < min ){ zoom = min, var zoomEnd = true; }
if(zoom > max){ zoom = max, var zoomEnd = true; }
```

Check if zoomEnd=true (i.e: zoom is at min or max zoom):

```
if(zoomEnd =true)
{ 
    d3.select('svg').classed('scroll', true)
} else{ 
    d3.select('svg').classed('scroll', false)) 
}
```

CSS:

```
.scroll{
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Remember, youll have to do this check every frame, so in a tick/update function so it always checks to see if the zoom is out of bounds so it brings in the scroll ability